# Get email address from each CN listed in a custom attribute

Tags: powershell, ldap

We have a custom attribute in our LDAP groups "groupManagers". This attribute will have a comma separated list of CN's of the managers. Such as:

> groupManagers : {CN=asmith,OU=STAFF,OU=US,DC=ad,DC=usnet,
> CN=bjones,OU=STAFF,OU=US,DC=ad,DC=usnet}

I would like to loop through AD groups that match a name pattern and get the Name and email address of each groupManager, format such as:

> ```
>  groupName
>  Andy Smith asmith@us.net
>  Bobby Jones bjones@us.net
> ```

So far, this is what I have, I'm getting the group Name and each user samAccounName to display, but do not know how to instead of each member get the displayName and email of each CN in the groupManagers attribute:

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter {name -like "*DirectReports"} | foreach {
    $currentGroup = $_.Name
    Get-ADGroup $currentGroup -Properties Name | Select Name
    Get-ADGroupMember -identity $currentGroup -Recursive | Get-ADUser -Property DisplayName | Select Name,ObjectClass,DisplayName
}
```

There will need to be another ForEach -- but I'm failing on getting that part figured out. Help appreciated!

Comment: Is this custom attribute a User attribute (like the standard `Manager` attrib) or an attribute added to the properties of a group?. P.S. What you describe are DistinguishedNames, but these already have commas.. How are the separate DNs delimited?

Comment: It is an attribute added to the properties of a group. The attribute value is the CN of each manager separated by a comma.

Comment: No, it is a multiline property. The way you show it in your question makes it look like a series of comma separated strings. It is an array of [Distinguished Names](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Distinguished%20Names)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because this custom attribute apparently is an array of DistinguishedNames (not just a list of comma separated names), you can do this:

```
# get a list of group objects, including the 'groupManagers' custom property
$result = Get-ADGroup -Filter "Name -like '*DirectReports'" -Properties groupManagers | ForEach-Object {
    $currentGroup = $_.Name
    # output an object with the desired properties
    foreach ($dn in $_.groupManagers) {
        Get-ADUser -Identity $dn -Property DisplayName, EmailAddress | 
        Select-Object @{Name = 'GroupName'; Expression = {$currentGroup}}, DisplayName, EmailAddress
    }
} 

# output as table on screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# output to structured CSV file
$result | Export-Csv -Path '<path\to\GroupManagers.csv>' -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation

# output as in your example
$result | Group-Object GroupName | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Name
    foreach ($mgr in $_.Group) {
        "$($mgr.DisplayName) $($mgr.EmailAddress)"
    }
    ""     # an empty line to separate the groups
}
```

Output on screen as Table:

```
GroupName DisplayName EmailAddress 
--------- ----------- ------------ 
GroupX    Andy Smith  asmith@us.net
GroupX    Bobby Jones bjones@us.net
GroupY    John Doe    jdoe@us.net
```

Output on screen in the format you want:

```
GroupX
Andy Smith asmith@us.net
Bobby Jones bjones@us.net

GroupY
John Doe jdoe@us.net
```

Comment: Works as requested, thank you for the alternative export format and export option.